# sentry not showing errors in issues

Tags: python, django, sentry

I have been using a Sentry for six months and it was works perfect

But Sentry has not been showing errors in Dashboard>Issues since nine days ago

errors saving in Transactions and showing in Dashboard>Performance but not showing in Dashboard>Issues

i integrate `sentry1.0.0` with `django2.2.*`

how can fix this? how show errors in Dashboard>Issues with errors log?

config in `settings.py`

```
sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="https://********************ac@o*****.ingest.sentry.io/******9",
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration()],
    traces_sample_rate=1.0,
    send_default_pii=True
)
```

Comment: This sounds like a case for Sentry support which you can reach from within the webapp

Comment: what you mean? i must send message to Sentry support? or i must doing something in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add new project and new team not helped

finally remove my Organization and add new project and it fixed